# Can't find header file with cmake

Tags: c, cmake, embedded, nrf51

I'm trying to compile a 'blinky' program for the nRF51422 chip, and I've been using CMake in Cygwin to create the makefile. (Bear in mind, I'm new at this.)

Here's my CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)
set(CMAKE_LEGACY_CYGWIN_WIN32 0)

project("nRF51422 Blinky" C)

add_executable(nRF51 main.c)
target_include_directories(nRF51 PUBLIC "X:/Documents/TestCompilation/RTE")
target_include_directories(nRF51 PUBLIC "X:/Programs/Keil_v5/ARM/Pack/ARM/CMSIS/4.2.0/CMSIS/Include")
target_include_directories(nRF51 PUBLIC "X:/Programs/Keil_v5/ARM/Pack/NordicSemiconductor/nRF_DeviceFamilyPack/1.1.4/Device/Include")
target_include_directories(nRF51 PUBLIC "X:/Programs/Keil_v5/ARM/Pack/NordicSemiconductor/nRF_Drivers/1.2.1/hal")
target_include_directories(nRF51 PUBLIC "X:/Programs/Keil_v5/ARM/Pack/NordicSemiconductor/nRF_Examples/7.2.0/bsp")
```

And I get this error when running cmake -G"Unix Makefiles" && make:

```
~/blinky/main.c:24:23: fatal error: nrf_delay.h: No such file or directory
#include "nrf_delay.h"
                      ^
compilation terminated
```

I know that the nrf_delay is located in the /nRF_Drivers/1.2.1/hal folder, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you inspect the compiler invocation command-line to see what the actual `-I` passed in is?

Comment: As a side note, you should require at least CMake 2.8.11, `target_include_directories()` was not present before this version.

Comment: Edited error description: The cmake runs fine, but the error comes when I run make
@Angew Updated to 2.8.11 - same result. And how do I inspect the includes?

Comment: Are you sure about the name of file? Are you sure about the path?

Comment: I saw posts where nrf_delay.h is places in  \components\drivers_nrf\hal

Comment: Maybe you can use INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES instead

Comment: @Like If `include_directories()` works, so will `target_include_directories()` (and vice versa).

Comment: Probably is too simple, but: have you tried to move all `target_include_directories` before `add_executable`?

Comment: @LPs If I do that, I get this error: `Cannot specify include directories for target "nRF51422" which is not built by this project.` If the `add_executable` is called after, then there exists no **target** to link to.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned:

- Build your project with `make -j1 VERBOSE=1` The `-j1` builds with one thread and aims to keep compiler output and error message together
- The compiler call before the error message must be corrected
- Review the includes and re-run it with the paths your are expecting